# Does Closure Library have an equivalent to jQuery.live?

Tags: google-closure-library

In jQuery I can use `live()` to add event listeners, even for elements that don't exist yet:

```
jQuery('a[href*="/item/"]', pageContent).live('click', preLoadAjaxPage);
```

Does Closure Library have an equivalent?

`goog.events.EventType` doesn't have any "DOM change" event, so I *can not* do `goog.events.listen(goog.dom.getDocument(), goog.events.EventType.DOM_CHANGE, addEventListenersAgain)` or similar.

Comment: You could just do what `.live` is doing: register an event handler at the root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed @Felix Kling's suggestion and registered the event handler at root:

```
goog.events.listen(document.body, goog.events.EventType.CLICK,
    /**
     * @param {goog.events.BrowserEvent} event
     */
    function(event) {
        var realEvent = event.event_;
        var el = /** @type {HTMLAnchorElement} */ (event).target;

        if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a' && (href matches pattern)) {
            // ...
        }
    });
```